# What is the regex for a URL like this?

Tags: regex

I don't really know regex, but would like a quick solution to search and replace links. I want to use the search regex wordpress plugin to remove links in my post. How do I format the regex to a link like this:

```
http://website.com/index.php?id=934&title=item name
```

edit: the numbers in the id and the item name varies

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, the regex `/http://website\.com/index\.php\?id=934&title=item name/` would certainly work, but I suspect you want to match other URLs that are similar. If that's correct, you really need to specify what parts are allowed to vary.

Comment: Wow that is a quick reply. The numbers in the id and the item name varies. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one out: http://regexr.com?2vjq6

Depending on whether or not you need whitespace in your "title" parameter, the regex I provided may need to be altered. Best practice would be to **not** have whitespace in your URLs (use URL encoding instead, where a space = %20).

```
http://website.com/index.php\?id=[0-9]*&title=[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*
```

Comment: I'm getting Invalid regular expression: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: @user1122581 - in your own code or from the link I posted? The link I posted is working fine for me.

Comment: @user1122581 - here's a slightly updated version which escapes all the reserved characters in the regex: http://regexr.com?2vjq6.

Comment: Thanks. I have whitespace in the item name, so it only gets the first word and not the second word though

Comment: @user1122581 - If you always have two words in your item name, you can use http://regexr.com?2vjq9. Otherwise, it's going to be very difficult (how will you distinguish between words in your item name and words that appear after it?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```